# XamlParseException in a dynamically loaded assembly

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8.1, dynamic-loading

I have a Windows 8.1 App and a Windows 8.1 portable library.

The app has no reference to the library (but the library is in the app's package).

In the library, I have a XAML page.

In the app, I load the assembly (`Assembly.Load("MyLibrary")`), I find my XAML page type, then, when calling the constructor of my page, the InitializeComponent method throws a XamlParseException, without anything inside that could give me information on what went wrong (no innerexception, no message except "XAML parsing failed"...)

When keeping exactly the same code but adding the reference to library, there is no problem, but I don't want to have that reference.

Could someone help?

Comment: I am having this EXACT issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: What I did to go around the problem is avoid XAML files and "write" my layout on the C# side (not as simple as xaml but you can do everything (binding, resources...)). That's clearly not a perfect solution, but it gets the job done.
However, it might (I said "might") have something to do with the .pri files. I guess that using them (don't know how) might solve the problem. If you manage to do it, tell me how ;)

Comment: Ok, that seems to work but it is really ugly... I'll poke around with the .pri files and see if I can get it to work. Thanks!